# Facebook comments count: Include threaded comments?

Tags: facebook, comments

I have fb:comments-count working on my website but it doesn't include nested/threaded comments in the count only top level comments. I couldn't find anything about this on the internet.

Is this by design or is there any other way to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

> The fb:comments-count tag will emit the number of comments on your URL
>   in a  tag.

Reading that line, I  believe that you have found a bug.  You should log it http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and report back the # here so others who come across this SO post can see it too.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/435128579850918/

According to FaceBook, this is by design. so the original question has not been answered.